# OpenJFX on Apple M1 chip

Tags: macos, gradle, javafx, apple-m1

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
```

I am trying to make OpenJFX to work on Apple MacOS Silicon M1 chip.
I use Gradle and it includes:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

javafx {
    sdk = '/Users/eosantigen/Documents/javafx-sdk-16'
    modules = ['javafx.controls']
}
```

but I get the error above when I do `gradle run`. I also use JDK11. I also get the same error on the official tutorial.

Anyone made it work with Gradle? Or Maven?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `sdK = ...`, add `version = "17-ea+2"` and try again?

Comment: it doesn't work. same thing.

Comment: Right, that won't work for now. There is [ongoing work](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8257222) to support M1, but there is no public release of it yet. It should be possible to build it from https://github.com/openjdk/jfx with the correct build settings.

Comment: so, it is because of the jdk 11 specifically? sorry, I didn't really understand, if this is resolved in later jdk versions. Thanks

Comment: No, I was talking about JavaFX itself. A new build is required that includes the changes I linked before.

Comment: Nonetheless, there are other vendors that distribute JavaFX bundled with the JDK that might provide (non-official) support for M1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Finally, I have tried OpenJDK 17 *(installed through SDKman, as usual)*, with the following in `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {

    id 'application'
        id "org.javamodularity.moduleplugin" version "1.8.10"
        id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.12'
}

javafx {
        version = '17'
        modules = ['javafx.controls']
}
```

And it runs perfectly. *(didn't try jdk-11 again with it.)*

Comment: And why not use 18 right away, at least for JavaFX in order to get the latest improvements and bug fixes?

Comment: @mipa because I generally prefer LTS versions and since it works, then, so far so good..  :)